# Why finally block is executing after calling sys.exit(0) in except block?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I just want to know why the `finally` block is executing after calling `sys.exit(0)` in the `except` block?

Code:

```
import sys

def divide_by_zero():
    try:
        10/0
        print "It will never print"
    except Exception:
        sys.exit(0)
        print "Printing after exit"
    finally:
        print "Finally will always print"

divide_by_zero()
```

Btw., I was just trying to do the same thing as in Java, where the `finally` block is *not* executed when `System.exit(0)` is in the `catch` block.

Comment: The "soft exit" is actually a very handy behavior. You can do `sys.exit(1)` when handling an exception and still be able to do some crucial final cleanup such as closing connections, files etc.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

All [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) does is raise an exception of type [`SystemExit`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the `SystemExit`
> exception, so cleanup actions specified by `finally` clauses of `try`
> statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
> attempt at an outer level.

If you run the following, you'll see for yourself:

```
import sys
try:
  sys.exit(0)
except SystemExit as ex:
  print 'caught SystemExit:', ex
```

As an alternative, [`os._exit(n)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os._exit) with the status code will stop the process bypassing much of the cleanup, including `finally` blocks etc.

Answer (score 10):

You should use `os._exit(0)`.

About your example:

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement,
> whether an exception has occurred or not.

This is from [Error and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) part of Python docs. So - your finally block will always be executed in example you show unless you will use `os._exit(0)`. But you should use it wisely...